# Send image to printer using sockets on port 9100

Tags: swift, sockets, printing, swift2

I'm currently able to send text to a printer (like EPSON TM20-II) using Swift. The printer receives the data and prints it without any problems. (For that, I'm encoding my string in UTF-8)

My custom class for the socket :

```
class OutSocket {

    var addr: String
    var port: Int
    var task: NSURLSessionStreamTask!

    init(host: String, port: Int){
        print("init")
        self.addr = host
        self.port = port
        setupConnection()
    }

    func setupConnection() {
        print("setup")
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: .defaultSessionConfiguration())

        task = session.streamTaskWithHostName(addr, port: port)
        self.task.resume()
    }

    func send(data: NSData) {
        self.task.writeData(data, timeout: 5.0) { (error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("Data sent")
            } else {
                print("Nope")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm using it like this :

```
let socket = OutSocket(host: "192.168.1.42", port: 9100)
socket.send((itemText + "\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

I can send an image to the printer, but it only prints me the data characters.
How can I print an image, and not the data characters ?

I saw the Epson SDK but I want it to works with any printer that support TCP/IP printing. I tried to encode my image in base64 but still not print the image.

here the code :

```
let socket = OutSocket(host: "192.168.1.42", port: 9100)
let image = UIImage(named: "name-logo")
let imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
let imgEncoded = imgData!.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
socket.send(imgEncoded)
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you use Epson printers, you can search for Epson ePos SDK. Otherwise, if you print the image yourself, you have to convert your image into Base64 encoded string.